# Coldfusion 2 queries comparison

Tags: coldfusion

I have 2 Query object in Coldfusion now I want to create a small report on account of these 2 queries

queries may look like

```
Q1

ID CODE NAME ACTIVE
```

and

```
Q2
CODE PRICE BOOKABLE
```

The code `CODE`
 field is common key between these 2 queries. Now I want to get records are that are in Q1 but not in Q2 and vice versa, how many recodes are common in both queries where `CODE` is unique.

Comment: I would always use the DB to do this kind of work, e.g @swetha's answer. It'll be more scalable, performant and testable. If the data really comes from two different databases, then use QoQ

Answer (score 4):

```
 <cfquery name="Q1" datasource="test">
       select * from users where code not in (select code from system)
 </cfquery>
 <cfquery name="Q2" datasource="test">
          select * from system where code not in (select code from users)
  </cfquery>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use QoQ  to solve this.

```
        <cfquery name="Q1" datasource="test">
            select * from table1
        </cfquery>

        <cfquery name="Q2" datasource="test">
            select * from table2
        </cfquery>

        <cfset q1code = valuelist(q2.code,"," )>
        <cfset q2code = valuelist(q1.code,"," )>

        <cfquery name="q3" dbtype="query" >
            select * from q1 where code Not in(#q1code#)
        </cfquery>

        <cfquery name="q4" dbtype="query" >
            select * from q2 where code Not in(#q2code#)
        </cfquery>

        <cfquery name="q5" dbtype="query" >
            select * from q1,q2 where q1.code = q2.code
        </cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with other people, make the DB do the work. If these are in the same db, then you do this to get the records common to both tables:

```
SELECT Q1.ID
  ,Q1.CODE 
  ,Q1.NAME 
  ,Q1.ACTIVE
  ,Q2.PRICE 
  ,Q2.BOOKABLE
FROM Q1, Q2
WHERE Q1.CODE = Q2.CODE
```

In order to do the first part of your question .. get the records that are in Q1 but not in Q2, you can do that with an outer_join if I am understanding you correctly. Syntax is different for all db's on doing outer joins. I always have to go look it up, so I'm not going to write it here.

another option is to union the two tables, and let cold fusion pull the reports on column_name = ''

```
select * from Q1 UNION SELECT * FROM Q2
```

-- you can't actually do this (select *) because of duplicate 'code' column in both dbs. 
you'll have to specify the columns explicitly and rename the first one to Q1Code, then Q2Code.

then in CF you do

```
<cfif q2Code EQ ''> print Q1: #Q1CODE# <cfelse> print Q2: #Q2CODE#  </cfif>
```

or maybe you want:

```
<cfif q1code EQ Q2code> yay they match</cfif>
```